# How to fetch record from sqlite database that has been created automatically when implemented in coredata

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, core-data

I have app in that i am using coredata. And when i install the app three files are getting created in the document directory called `“test.sqlite, test.sqlite-shm and test.sqlite-wal"`. And now in second app i copy the test.sqlite in the folder and i want to access the database and tables but i got error like this "no such table found".  Is there any issue that i create the database with coredata?  please help me.

Comment: why are you copying the test.sqlite to your second app? As it is saving values in the first app.You can't use the database of one app into another.

Comment: @Stark I have to apps first app i use coredata for item list and. And other app i want to show the records of item in the second app so i call the other app in my first app.

Comment: Its looking all messed up you can save and show your records in one app alone then why using two apps?

Comment: @Stark In first app i load item list from webservice and store in to coredata.And when i call second app from my first app it also load item list from the webservice. But second time i dont want to call webservice and load datafrom the test.sqlite database.

Comment: Will you please explain it in more detail with your code? just edit your question, So we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to:

1. send all of the `sqlite*` files that Core Data creates
2. export the content from the data store, format it and send that

Option 1 should work and be fast to implement, but it isn't very future proof. Option 2 will take longer but is a much better solution.